# calculating conditional probability-bayes rule

Tags: probability, bayesian

I'd like to calculate the conditional probability in the following case:
I was told that a box contains a BLUE ball. this is my evidence, my prior probability of a BLUE being drawn is 0.3. and this message can come from a friend(0.6) or an enemy (0.4)

I also know the probabilities of:
a friend observing BLUE : 0.16
a friend observing RED: 0.09
an enemy observing BLUE: 0.05
an enemy observing RED: 0.17 given that the ball is actually BLUE.

I would like to know the conditional probability of the ball actually being BLUE given this information.